# cmbright and dvipng error

Tags: dvipng

Using latest MikTeX, under Windows 10. If I compile the following MWE (bottom) to a .dvi file, and then either look at it with yap, or .dvi -> .ps -> .pdf, file renders fine.  However, if I try to convert the .dvi to a .png file using dvipng (which comes bundled with MikTeX), I get the following fatal error:

```
 C:\Users\egc\Desktop\egc\text\TeX notes\mwe>dvipng cmbright_demo.dvi
   This is dvipng 1.16 Copyright 2002-2015, 2019 Jan-Ake Larsson

   dvipng: Fatal error, PK file 

   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/cx/public
     /cmbright/dpi480\cmbr10.pk ends prematurely
```

If I comment out cmbright, and simply use default (cm), no error at all. dvipng creates a png file. If I try a differnt font package, say, \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}, again, no problem at all. The problem seems to arise with cmbright. So, not sure if the problem is with cmbright, dvipng, or some interaction between the two. I'd like to sort this out, since cmbright is my go-to for san serif with math support.

Any suggestions? Thanks much...

Here is the MWE:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage{cmbright}

 \begin{document}

  Here is a simple equation

    \begin{equation}
       \frac{dN}{dt}=rN\left(1-\frac{N}{K}\right)
    \end{equation}

 Now some random text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
 elit. Sed et pharetra ligula, quis consequat nunc. Suspendisse potenti. 
 Donec purus nibh, vestibulum et massa sit amet, dapibus accumsan magna. 
 Aliquam vitae ante auctor, vestibulum sapien in, pellentesque dolor. 
 Suspendisse laoreet luctus ex. Fusce ornare vestibulum neque eu rutrum.
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In reading the cmbright docs, I noticed references to cm-super, and hfbright. I installed both packages, and, problem gone. dvipng now works perfectly.